# mininet pingall sometimes fails with remote controller

Tags: sdn, mininet

Can someone explains me the reason why the pingall sometimes works and sometimes doesn't.
I'm using mininet with remote contreller floodlight.
thanks in advance

Comment: did you configure loss rate on your links?

Comment: @Amin no I didn't, for the moment I can't ping at all and I don't know what is the problem